# pyspark timestamp changing when creating parquet file

Tags: pyspark, timestamp

I am creating a dataframe and saving it as parquet format.
after creating dataframe when i did df.show() i have correct timestamp displaying but when i used df.write.parquet("filename") . it is changing timestamp .

orginal time stamps when i did df.show()     2018-02-27 07:15:00 , 2018-07-06 14:23:00

after creating parquet and reading from that parquet file - 2018-02-27 02:15:00 , 2018-07-06 10:23:00

There is either 5 hours difference or 4 hours difference .Any idea what is happening. Thanks for reading

Comment: are you using hive metastore for parquet?

Comment: We are not using hive metastore